# How can I run a Unity game in a window larger than the desktop resolution?

Tags: unity, resolution, screen, viewport

I am exploring a research problem using Unity. I require a game resolution of at least 4096 x 786. There seems to be no option under build settings for setting a fixed screen size window. (The default screen width and height options are unhelpful here.)

How can I make a window even larger than the desktop?

Comment: Don't you mean you need a *canvas* of that size? It doesn't make a lot of sense to say that you're looking for a software solution to needing more pixels in your screen than you have.

Comment: Scrolling over a bigger-than-screen-res canvas can definitely be done, but it has little to to with the screen size in the build settings.

Answer (score 2):

As we can see in the documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html) on `Screen.SetResolution`:

> A width by height resolution will be used. If no matching resolution is supported, the closest one will be used.

So what it will do is downgrade that to a supported width/height. This applies even if it's in windowed mode as opposed to full screen (at least in the version I'm using: 4.5.2). It should, however, work just fine as long as the monitor you're using supports that resolution.

The code used to programmatically change resolution is:

```
Screen.SetResolution(4096, 786, false);
```

Note also that on the build settings you can disable the resolution dialog that pops up before your game runs and you can define the aspect ratios and such that your game supports AND that resolution functions like this will usually have limited/no effect if running within the editor.

Comment: It did let me set ridiculous resolution like 100x100 or alike.

Answer (score -3):

You can't make one bigger than your monitor.

Comment: Please provide supporting information to back this up and improve the answer. As it stands this is barely more than a comment.